# Error messages from compiling the Piecewise function

Tags: bugs, compile, piecewise

The following works

```
Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Piecewise[{{{0., 0.}, x > 5.}}, {1., 1.}]]
```

but if I enter the `Piecewise[...]` in the bracket style, I get two error messages

> Compile::cif: The types of the two results in If[True,{1.,1.},0] are incompatible because their ranks are different. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
>
> Compile::cif: The types of the two results in If[x>5.,{0.,0.},If[True,{1.,1.},0]] are incompatible because their ranks are different. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>

It seems the bracket style input form of the `Piecewise` function is transformed into

```
If[x>5.,{0.,0.},If[True,{1.,1.},0]]
```

and `0` has a different type than `{1.,1.}`.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

`In[2]` works as expected, but when I type the bracket style of `Piecewise` in `In[3]`, it doesn't work. However, if I copy the output bracket style of `Piecewise` in `Out[2]` and put it in `In[4]`, it works again.

Why this happens and how to fix it? Am I making stupid mistakes or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a complete answer as I don't know precisely why this happens, unless we account for it as a simple omission in/limitation of the compiler (which it could well be). Nonetheless, I can at least tell you *what* is happening.

As you know, `Compile` has `HoldAll`. The fact that the `Piecewise` is not evaluated before being seen by `Compile` when entered directly as a bracket leads to its translation into slightly different code.

The evaluated form of the `Piecewise` is:

```
Piecewise[{{{0., 0.}, x > 5.}}, {1., 1.}]
```

`Compile` correctly translates this into code completely equivalent to:

```
If[x > 5., {0., 0.}, {1., 1.}]
```

However, when faced with the unevaluated form as entered using the bracket, i.e.

```
Piecewise[{{{0., 0.}, x > 5.}, {{1., 1.}, True}}]
```

it produces (as you rightly say)

```
If[x > 5., {0., 0.}, If[True, {1., 1.}, 0]]
```

which is not compilable due to the obvious mismatch in tensor rank between `{1., 1.}` and `0`. We can fix the problem at this stage by substituting `{0., 0.}` in place of `0`, but not by simply removing the `0` (as this is interpreted as `Null`, which is of a special `Null` or "void" type). A better way is simply to remove the redundant nested `If` and place the default value directly in the body of the enclosing `If`.

Alternatively, we might manually do the same transformation that evaluation effects:

```
Hold@Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Piecewise[{{{0., 0.}, x > 5.}, {{1., 1.}, True}}]] /. 
  HoldPattern@Piecewise[{conds__List, {default_, True}}] :>
    Piecewise[{conds}, default] // ReleaseHold
```

However, my personal preference would be to avoid `Piecewise` and similar functions when writing compilable code. As we saw above, the compiler cannot work with these directly, instead translating them into nested `If`s before compilation. In my opinion, it is much less likely to lead to errors and oddities of the sort encountered here if one uses only constructs that have direct equivalents in bytecode, and hence for which one can predict to a reasonable degree of accuracy what the compiled code will actually be.

Comment: Nice answer. For future readers, use `Which` instead of `Piecewise`.