# Compile error from If but not from Piecewise

Tags: compile, piecewise, conditional

Consider this:

```
point={1.,2.};
f1 = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, 
  Evaluate[Block[{a, b}, {a, b} = point; If[t > 0., a*b*Sin[t], 0.]]]];
f1[2.]
```

> CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression a should be a machine-size
>   real number. >>
>   CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 5; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>

```
(*0.909297 a b*)
```

and this:

```
f2 = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, 
  Evaluate[Block[{a, b}, {a, b} = point;Piecewise[{{a*b*Sin[t], t > 0.}, {0., True}}]]]];
f2[2.]
(*1.81859*)
```

Why does the `If` version produce errors while the `Piecewise` one doesn't? From [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28336/1364) I believe the compiler transforms the `Piecewise` function into its equivalent `If` function before compilation, so f1 and f2 should be the same. Why the difference?

Comment: @Nasser I need the `Evaluate` because in my real code there are some piecewise functions I want to expand before compile, which makes the code run 2x faster in my case.

Comment: @xslittlegrass, then why do you not pass the `Pieceswise` as an argument to a function that will return the `CompiledFunction`?

Comment: If what you have is piecewise functions, have you tried `PiecewiseExpand` in place of `Evaluate` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By trial and error, this works. It is where you put the `Evaluate`

```
point = {1., 2.};
f1 = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, 
  Block[{a, b}, {a, b} = point; Evaluate@If[t > 0., a*b*Sin[t], 0.]]]

f1[1.2]  
Out[354]= 1.86408
```

for the other one

```
ff2 = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, 
   Block[{a, b}, {a, b} = point; 
    Evaluate[Piecewise[{{a*b*Sin[t], t > 0.}, {0., True}}]]]];

ff2[1.2]
Out[9]= 1.86408
```

So, may be you can put the needed `Evaluate` around the expression in question instead of around the whole `Block`? Putting outside the `Block` seems to have not affected the `If` part for some reason. I am not a Mathematica language expert to know why that is. But the above works.

Answer (score 6):

#### Compiling with If

The reason `f1` does not work is that

```
Block[{a, b}, {a, b} = point; If[t > 0., a*b*Sin[t], 0.]]
```

evaluates to

> ```
> If[t > 0., a b Sin[t], 0.]
> ```

That happens because `If` is `HoldRest` and `t > 0.` does not evaluate to `True` or `False`.  When compiled, there are `MainEvaluate` calls to evaluate `a` and `b`, which will give an error if `a` or `b` is not a real numeric quantity.  So while `f1[2.]` gives an error, the following

```
Block[{a, b}, {a, b} = point; f1[2.]]
```

yields

> ```
> 1.81859
> ```

---

Note what happens if a third argument is supplied to `If`:

```
f3 = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, 
 Evaluate[Block[{a, b}, {a, b} = point; 
          If[t > 0., a*b*Sin[t], 0., -200.]]]]
(* CompiledFunction[{t}, -200., -CompiledCode-] *)
```

The value of `f3[-1.]`, `f3[2.]` etc. will always be `-200.`

#### Compiling with Piecewise

While `Piecewise` is `HoldAll`, it evaluates each piece in turn until one of the conditions is `True`.  What actually seems to happen is a little complicated and not completely described in the reference page [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html) (more below).  The behavior of `Compile` can be understood by the same means as for `If`:

```
Block[{a, b}, {a, b} = point; Piecewise[{{a * b * Sin[t], t > 0.}, {0., True}}]]
(* Piecewise[{{2.*Sin[t], t > 0.}}, 0.] *)
```

The values of `a` and `b` are substituted, and this is the expression that is compiled.  So in both cases, `If` and `Piecewise`, there is not a problem with `Compile`.  The difference is explained by the expression that is compiled.

*The behavior of Piecewise:*
Why are do values of `a`, `b` end up in the `Piecewise` expression that is the output of `Block`?
Consider

```
Piecewise[{{val$1, cond$1},
           {val$2, cond$2},
           ...
 ]
```

Each condition `cond$n` is evaluated in turn.  If `cond$n` evaluates to `False`, `Piecewise` proceeds to the next condition.  If `cond$n` does not evaluate to `False`, then `val$n` is evaluated; if the condition evaluates to neither `True` nor `False`, then the values of `val$n` and `cond$n` become part of a `Piecewise` expression that is returned after evaluation. That is how the values of `a` and `b` end up in the output.

Applying this procedure to the OP's `f2`, we see that `a*b*Sin[t]` will be evaluated during the evaluation of `Piecewise` and the values of `a` and `b` will replace the variables.

Example: The first condition evaluates to `False` and `x` is not incremented by `1`.  The next evaluates to `-3 > a`; `x` is incremented by 10, printed, and the value `{2. 10}` becomes a value in the final `Piecewise` expression that is returned.  Finally, the last condition is `True`, so the third value is evaluated; since not all the preceding conditions evaluated to `False`, a `Piecewise` expression is returned.

```
Clear[a, t];
x = 0;
t = -3;
Piecewise[{{Print[x += 1];   {1., x}, t > 0.},
           {Print[x += 10];  {2., x}, t > a},
           {Print[x += 100]; {3., x}, True}
  }]
(* 10 *)
(* 110 *)
(* Piecewise[{{{2., 10}, -3 > a}}, {3., 110}] *)
```

I might note that `Piecewise` is described in the reference manual as representing "a piecewise function", but it's not a function in the *Mathematica* sense: if
    `f = Piecewise[..]`
then `f[x]` does **not** evaluate to the value of the piecewise function at `x`.

---

That's an explanation of why OP's code behaves the way it does. Your `f2` already works the way you expected, but if you'd like another way, then consider this:

```
point = {1., 2.};
f4 = With[{a = point[[1]], b = point[[2]]}, 
   Compile[{{t, _Real}}, If[t > 0., a*b*Sin[t], 0.]]];
f4[2.]
(* 1.81859 *)
```